# Set paramenter of a function using difftime and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

How can I set the paramenter `units ="mins"` in the following function as a parameter?

This is just the data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

u <- runif(10, 0, 60) 
w <- runif(10, 0, 60) 

df <- tibble(time_1 = as.POSIXct(u, origin = "2019-02-03 08:00:00"),
       time_2 = as.POSIXct(w, origin = "2019-02-03 08:30:00"))
```

This is my funtion. I would like to be able to change the paramenter for difftime and set it as a parameter, e.g. units = "months".

```
time_diff <- function(df, stamp1, stamp2){

  stamp1 <- enquo(stamp1)
  stamp2 <- enquo(stamp2)

  name <- paste0(quo_name(stamp1), "_", quo_name(stamp2))

  df %>% 
    mutate(!!name := difftime(!!stamp1, !!stamp2, units="mins"))
}

df %>% 
  time_diff(time_2, time_1)
```

But I would like something like this:

```
df %>% 
      time_diff(time_2, time_1, mins)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just adding the `units` parameter? e.g.

```
time_diff <- function(df, stamp1, stamp2, units="mins"){

  stamp1 <- enquo(stamp1)
  stamp2 <- enquo(stamp2)

  name <- paste0(quo_name(stamp1), "_", quo_name(stamp2))

  df %>% 
    mutate(!!name := difftime(!!stamp1, !!stamp2, units=units))
}
```

Then you can do `df %>% time_diff(time_2, time_1, "mins")`.